# R: How to remove internal nodes label=NA in treedata

Tags: r, ggtree

I would like to know if there is a way to remove the internal node labels in my treedata file. Right now I have 'NA's showing up in my phylogenetic tree when visualizing the treedata using ggtree since there is no external data associated with these internal nodes generated by tree programs.

I first generated the phylogenetic tree using iqtree, then I imported the tree into R and converted to tidy data frame so that I can combine this tree with an external dataset that tells me the lineage numbers associated with each tip node. I converted the joined tidy data frame back to treedata file, and finally visualizing/annotating using ggtree.

It would be great to know a way to make the internal node label=NAs disappear in my ggtree.

Thank you so much

Comment: Could you please share your code and some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.